# How I should check indentation in SASS file with stylelint?

Tags: css, sass, coding-style, stylesheet, stylelint

I try to use stylelint to check my SASS files. When I set rule

```
"indentation": "tab"
```

stylelint throws next erros

```
 2:1   ✖  Expected indentation of 1 tab   indentation
 3:1   ✖  Expected indentation of 1 tab   indentation
 5:1   ✖  Expected indentation of 1 tab   indentation
 8:3   ✖  Expected indentation of 1 tab   indentation
11:3   ✖  Expected indentation of 1 tab   indentation
14:3   ✖  Expected indentation of 1 tab   indentation
....
```

how to check indent correctly?

UPD: 
top of the styles:

```
@import "theme/bootstrap"
@import "theme/bootstrap-theme"
@import "theme/theme"

@keyframes hide-notifi

    0%
        top: 0

    75%
        top: 0

    100%
        top: -100%
```

Comment: Can you add lines 2 to 5 of your SCSS code to the question please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stylelint is not currently compatible with the whitespace-based SASS syntax.

To quote the [stylelint.io](http://stylelint.io/) website:

> **Understands CSS-like syntaxes**: The linter is powered by PostCSS, so it
>   understands any syntax that PostCSS can parse, including SCSS,
>   SugarSS, and *experimental support* for Less.

You could adopt [SugarSS](https://github.com/postcss/sugarss), which is a whitespace-based syntax. When combined with the [precss PostCSS plugin pack](https://github.com/jonathantneal/precss), you'll have something comparable to whitespace-based SASS.

Another option is contributing a SASS parser to the PostCSS community.

Alternatively, you can use [SASS-lint](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint) which supports SASS syntax, but has a different set of features to stylelint.